# Upload data to Yesod server using input forms

Tags: angularjs, haskell, file-upload, yesod

What is a correct way to uploading files via *custom* input forms in Yesod?

I developed a frontend in AngularJS, and I pass data to and from the server via JSON objects. However, this does not work when uploading files. For this reason I resorted to forms.

Gathering different resources I ended up with the following code. On the client side I use the following function:

```
this.submitNewMeas = function() {
    var selected_file = document.getElementById('measurements').files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("measurementsFile", selected_file);

    var response =  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/measurements/'+this.currMedia.id,
    headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    data: {
                fd
    },
    transformRequest: formDataObject
    });
    ...
    };
```

And on the server side I receive data as follows:

```
postMeasurementsR :: MediaId -> Handler Value
postMeasurementsR mediaId =  do
result <- runInputPost $ iopt fileField "measurementsFile"
case result of
    Just fileInfo -> do
        saveMeas fileInfo "measDir"

saveMeas :: FileInfo -> FilePath -> HandlerT App IO (FilePath)
saveMeas file dest = do
  let filename = unpack $ fileName file
      dest = dest </> filename
  liftIO $ fileMove file dest
  return filename
```

However this causes a server error

```
20/Nov/2014:13:40:15 +0100 [Error#yesod-core] <<loop>> @(yesod-core-1.4.3:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:502:5)
Status: 500 Internal Server Error 54.70131s
```

If I don't try to save the data, then the file information is received, and I am able to see the file name on the server.

I've successfully managed to upload files using Yesod forms, but when it comes to custom forms all my attempts so far have failed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dest = dest </> filename
```

That's the source of your infinite loop: you're saying "dest is defined as itself plus filename." What's happening is that you're *shadowing* the original declaration of `dest`. A simple solution is to call the second declaration something like `dest'` (or better yet, something even more informative).

Comment: This is telling me that I need to take some rest. I cannot believe I overlooked this! Thank you Michael.

Comment: GHC option -Wall would have warned you.